# How to reduce exponentiation expressions?

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

It is a simple question but I am afraid of its simplicity.

Is that correct : $2^{30}+2^{30}+2^{30}+2^{30} = 2^{30}(1 + 1 + 1  + 1) = (2^{30})\cdot 4 = 2^{30}\cdot2^2 = 2^{32}$?

I am doing complex exponentiation expressions and I need to simplify them but I do not know if this method is correct.

Comment: yes. that is correct.

Comment: Just consider $a=2^{30}$. You can comprehend it much more easily then since $a+a+a+a=4a=2^2a$

Comment: @cgo I know it's short, but could you please post your comment as an answer so this question can be removed from the "unanswered" queue?

Answer (score 2):

Yep, that's the right way to go about it. Factoring is a powerful tool with these kinds of problems.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1050343)

Comment: @MonkeyKing The question was answered in the comments, so without an actual answer, it will sit in the "unanswered" queue for the rest of time. See [this Meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1559/dealing-with-answers-in-comments) and [this one](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4423/unanswered-questions) for more discussion of questions that have been answered in the comments. Moreover, the question is, essentially, *"Is this correct?"*, and since the method is indeed correct, what more could be put in an answer besides some variation on "yes?"

Comment: Oh I'm really sorry I only reviewed 20 low quality posts and met this situation for first time. Should I unflag or something?

Comment: That's okay! Unfortunately, there are lots of posts that have ended up like this, so I'm glad you know how to handle them now. Unflagging would be the best course of action for now.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain? How can this question be answered better?

Comment: I upvoted because I don't see anything wrong with your post. You even made it community wiki from the start!